# External Gateway to foward traffic

Tags: tcp, portforwarding, forward

I want to use a Linux Maschine hosted in another Datacenter to forward traffic to my internal network. Basically I want to use the Linux Maschine as a Gateway to forward the traffic.

For example I want to access `external_ip:80` and forward it to `internal_wan_ip:60001`, on my firewall(fortigate) the port will accept connection only from the external_ip and its mapped to the right server and right port.

Whats the best approach to this?